# Is it possible to change distance in links table in AequilibraE plugin?

Tags: qgis, sqlite

I'm in a project, which want to compute fastest path for container truck with some path are blocked. I am using QGIS with plugin AequilibraE (get data from OSM) to solve it, but I can't describe blocked path in data. After that, I think if I change the distance (in database) of blocked path to very large, the algorithms compute the fastest path never go through it. But, I found this in the docs of AequilibraE plugin :

> **3.4.2.3.1.3.1. Link distance**   Link distance cannot be changed by the user, as it is automatically recalculated using the SpatiaLite
> function GeodesicLength, which always returns distances in meters.
> http://aequilibrae.com/python/latest/project_docs/network.html

So is there a way to change it at any cost, or is there a better way to describe blocked path?
P/s: AequilibraE using SQLite database.

Comment: More clearly, some areas are of traffic-high density, then the fastest path should be different. I want to find the fastest path with respect to variational velocity-path  between nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to disclose that I am the main developer of AequilibraE.

You cannot overwrite the distance in the length field in AequilibraE, but you can create a new field with whatever metric you want (penalized distance, travel time, generalized cost, etc.) and use that field to do any and all path computations you would like.

The documentation for the Python library (which powers the plugin) explains how it is done (by setting the graph to use the field you choose).

https://aequilibrae.com/python/latest/_auto_examples/plot_path_and_skimming.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-path-and-skimming-py

Comment: Thank you Pedro, your answer is everything i need to sovle my problem

Comment: P/s: i know you, because i watched many video of your channel on youtube. Thanks for support